# Add row that is wider than wrapper

Tags: html, css

I've got centered container with fixed width, inside it I have an element that must be full width of browser.

```
<div style="width: 960px; margin: 0 auto;">
    ...content...
    <div style="width 100% ??;"></div>
    ...content...
</div>
```

My question is, is there any way to make it work without wrapping just top and bottom part of content?

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: If you give it an absolute position, then move it back down into place, yes...

Comment: Does the top gray part have static height?  If so, you can position the red element absolutely to the left and however many pixels from the top.

Comment: Top part has dynamic height :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as the container is statically positioned, you can use `position: absolute`:

```css
left: 0;
position: absolute;
right: 0;
```

Note that you *don't need to set the `top` at all, nor does the top part need to have a static height*.

Comment: Thank you very much! This did the trick. Hope it works cross browser too.

Comment: @tMagwell: It does! One of very few things that isn't broken on IE7 :)